# Using Matplotlib's Hexbin to Create Heatmap

Tags: python, geolocation, matplotlib, geospatial

I am not a programmer but I have been doing some data analysis using Python lately and recently stumbled across Matplotlib.  I have a series of geo-coordinate data points that I am trying to visualize.  The data consists of geo coordinates and the sqft of each location:

latitude, longitude, SQFT

I have about 25k of these data points and I would like to show the cumulative sqft of these on a 2d image; basically create a heatmap of the sqft.  I have managed to use Matplotlib to create a hexbin with the lat and long data but this only gives me a count of the number of times an item falls into the bin.  I cannot figure out how I incorporate the sqft into the bins.  I have looked at the matplotlib docs and found that I can enter an additional variable, they call C, but I can't figure out how I need to format the data (or if this will even do what I need it to).

Comment: Are your latitude and longitude points uniformly spaced on a grid?  As for the matplotlib function `hexbin`, the `x`, `y`, and `C` variables should be vectors corresponding to longitude, latitude, and sqft respectively.  You'll also want to specify the argument `reduce_C_function` to be `sum` rather than the default `mean`.

Comment: @BrianL: Thanks! That worked.  The reduce_C_function is what I needed to change. You are the man!

Comment: @jason995, please post an answer below with the explicit code for your solution and select that as the answer

Comment: Agreed. If you found your own answer, please add it here so that everybody can benefit.

Comment: Your title is wrong. **Matlab** isn't **Matplotlib.**

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [@Brian L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/855026/brian-l)'s comment, to get cumulative square foot value in each cell you need to change `reduce_C_function` to `sum`. This means Matplotlib will use the Python `sum` function (the default is a mean function) to determine the color of that bin, based on `C` (in this case, SQFT). Below is an example using randomly-generated data.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

N = 158                             # OP said 25k datapoints; sqrt(25000) ~ 158
latitude = np.random.standard_normal(N**2) 
longitude = 12 * np.random.standard_normal(N**2) 

var = 100
SQFT = 1_000*np.exp(-(latitude**2 + longitude**2)/2/var)/2/np.pi/var + 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.hexbin(longitude, latitude, C=SQFT, gridsize=50, reduce_C_function=sum)
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, label="SQFT")
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude")
fig.show()
```

[image]